# Is there a way to prevent index wrapping?

Tags: python, matrix

I have the following:

```
# Possible neighbors as tuples
UP = (-1,0)
DOWN = (1,0)
LEFT = (0,-1)
RIGHT = (0,1)
POTENTIAL_NEIGHBORS = (UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT)

def LocateNeighbors(self):
        print '\nWorking on: {}:{}'.format(self.index,self.value)
        for n in POTENTIAL_NEIGHBORS:
            try:
                if theBoard[self.index[0]+n[0]][self.index[1]+n[1]]:
                    print "Adding neighbor: " + theBoard[self.index[0]+n[0]][self.index[1]+n[1]]
                    self.neighbors.append(n)
            except IndexError:
                print 'failed on: {}'.format(n)
```

.. where `self` is a cell within a game board such as:

```
      A      B      C      D      E      F
1 | {66} | {76} | {28} | {66} | {11} | {09}
-------------------------------------------
2 | {31} | {39} | {50} | {08} | {33} | {14}
-------------------------------------------
3 | {80} | {76} | {39} | {59} | {02} | {48}
-------------------------------------------
4 | {50} | {73} | {43} | {03} | {13} | {03}
-------------------------------------------
5 | {99} | {45} | {72} | {87} | {49} | {04}
-------------------------------------------
6 | {80} | {63} | {92} | {28} | {61} | {53}
-------------------------------------------
```

However, this is the output I get for the first cell I'm checking (`0,0`):

```
Working on: (0, 0):66
Adding neighbor: 80
Adding neighbor: 31
Adding neighbor: 09
Adding neighbor: 76
```

Essentially, if the index is (*what I would consider to be*) invalid, it's wrapping around to the end of the list. Is there a way to prevent, or at least detect this behavior? Or, perhaps a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a check along the lines of:

```
if (0 <= (self.index[0] + n[0]) < num_cols) and 
   (0 <= (self.index[1] + n[1]) < num_rows):
    # Do stuff here
```

That way you should hopefully also avoid an `IndexError` when you are at the opposite edges of the board.

Edit:

Daniel's reply is more Pythonic, I think. It follows the [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) principle.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a range checker-function:

```
def check(n):
    if n<0:
        raise IndexError(n)
    return n

def LocateNeighbors(self):
    print '\nWorking on: {}:{}'.format(self.index,self.value)
    for n in POTENTIAL_NEIGHBORS:
        try:
            if theBoard[check(self.index[0]+n[0])][check(self.index[1]+n[1])]:
                print "Adding neighbor: " + theBoard[self.index[0]+n[0]][self.index[1]+n[1]]
                self.neighbors.append(n)
        except IndexError:
            print 'failed on: {}'.format(n)
```